# Bootstrap grid dynamic columns

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following table on my page:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="Type in Types">    
                <img ng-src="../../Images/{{Type.TypeImg}}" ng-click="GoNext(Type.TypeId)" alt="{{Type.TypeName}}" />
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use bootstrap grid instead of the table. So if there were 3 images on the page I'd have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
</div>
```

But since the number of images is dynamic ( although it is never greater then 12), i cannot use fixed numbers in col-md*. So I'd have to do something like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="Type in Types">
    <div class="col-md-{{12 / Types.length}}">
        <img ng-src="../../Images/{{Type.TypeImg}}" ng-click="GoNext(Type.TypeId)" alt="{{Type.TypeName}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I have each image in its own row, instead of in a column(one under the another). How do i get them all in one line?

Comment: you have to use ng-class to set the col-md-i dynamically . Have some width in type hash. so for each image used that to set the ng-class = { Type.width: true }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `ng-repeat` to col:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-{{width}}" ng-repeat="Type in Types">
      {{$index}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZvkRpIQQxkCG1IUoSFHd?p=preview) see in full screen mode

Comment: where does "width" come from?

Comment: @ElenaDBA please look at plunk, it is set in controller